# Updating table is not happening through Setters in Spring JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am new to Spring boot and Spring Data JPA . So here i am trying to implement a sample project where a employee has list of workers , while adding a new worker has employee details also to indicate that he works for particular employee.  I am able to update the worker table and also fetch the details perfectly . Am trying to update Employee table as well so that while fetching a particular employee i want the list of workers associated with him also to be fetched . But that is not happening , i haven't used any query so far as it seems simple updation and i thought just save and setters would help to do so .

**Employee.Java**

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

@Id
private int empId;

private String empName;
private String location;

@OneToMany
private List<Worker> workers;



public Employee(){

}


public Employee(int empId, String empName, String location) {
    super();
    this.empId = empId;
    this.empName = empName;
    this.location = location;
}

public List<Worker> getWorkers() {
    return workers;
}


public void setWorkers(List<Worker> workers) {
    this.workers = workers;
}


public int getEmpId() {
    return empId;
}
public void setEmpId(int empId) {
    this.empId = empId;
}
public String getEmpName() {
    return empName;
}
public void setEmpName(String empName) {
    this.empName = empName;
}
public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}
public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}


public void setWorkers(Worker worker) {
    this.workers.add(worker);

}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Employee [empId=" + empId + ", empName=" + empName + ", location=" + location + ", workers=" + workers
            + "]";
}

/*@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Employee [empId=" + empId + ", empName=" + empName + ", location=" + location + "]";
}*/
```

**Worker.Java**

```
@Entity
public class Worker {

@Id
private int id;

private String name;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="empId")
private Employee employee;



public Worker(int id, String name , int empId) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.employee = new Employee(empId,"","");
}

public Worker() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Employee getEmployee() {
    return employee;
}

public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
    this.employee = employee;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

**WorkerController.Java**

```
@RestController
public class WorkerController {

@Autowired
WorkerRepository workerService;

@Autowired
EmployeeRepository employeeService;



@GetMapping("/employees/{id}/workers")
public List<Worker> getAllWorker(@PathVariable("id") int empId){
    return workerService.findByEmployeeEmpId(empId);
}

@PostMapping("/employees/{id}/workers")
public String addNewEmployee(@RequestParam("name") String name ,
        @RequestParam("workerId") int id , @PathVariable("id") int empId){
     Worker worker = new Worker();
     List<Worker> workers = new ArrayList<Worker>();
     worker.setId(id);
     worker.setName(name);
     worker.setEmployee(new Employee(empId,"",""));
     workerService.save(worker);
     workers.add(worker);
     employeeService.findById(empId).get().setWorkers(workers);
     Employee emp = new Employee();
     emp = employeeService.findById(empId).get();
     return "Successfully added";
     }

     }
```

After adding worker , i retrieve the following as output

```
[
{
    "id": 108,
    "name": "vijay",
    "employee": {
        "empId": 99,
        "empName": "darsha",
        "location": "mumbai",
        "workers": []
    }
},
{
    "id": 110,
    "name": "suraj",
    "employee": {
        "empId": 99,
        "empName": "darsha",
        "location": "mumbai",
        "workers": []
    }
}
]
```

but while retrieving i could see the employee table is not updated. can someone guide me .

```
{
"empId": 99,
"empName": "darsha",
"location": "mumbai",
"workers": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You says:

> "...while fetching a particular employee i want the list of workers
>   associated with him also to be fetched"

then you have to write a OneToMany Relationship on employee's side. What you do is you tries to fetch for each Worker one Employee which is of course working and is there in your JSON result.

Here is a OneToMany Example on Emplyees class side:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="employee", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Worker> worker = new ArrayList<>();
```

Note: mappedBy have to refer to the variable `Emplyee employee` in your Worker Class.

Please try different fetch types also.

Comment: i implemented what you have answered. but now its printing employee details n types like for employee ->worker list again in worker ->employee as it is goes on . how to restrict that and why is it happening . because of mapping one to many and many to one at the same time ??/

Comment: I know about that issue. I think this is not n times, you look n times over the same object which have every time the same variable on it. Per default every bean in Spring is a Singelton (one static object). But I really don't know. May you have to make a decision either its a one to many or its a many to one relationship.

Comment: why so?? is it not possible to map like that? what is the best way to implement it??

Comment: How do you will do that ? When you ask for worker which have an Many to One relationship you get that worker with that relationship. Thats what you want because you write your code for it. If you don't want that, try to make two Worker Entities (one with Many to One Relationship and one without that relationship) and ask any time from your employees that Worker Entity without that Many to One Relationship. As alternate implement only these relationship which is more important for your business logic. hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not getting your `@OneToMany` attributes is due fetch type is lazy by default for all `@OneToMany` associations like list, set.

To overcome this problem. Change the default lazy fetch to eager fetch.

Modify your entity mapping to this.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="employee", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL) private List<Worker> worker = new ArrayList<>();
```

while fetching you may get recursive mapping. To avoid this just add `@JsonIgnoreProperties`  to your employee field in worker class.

Example:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties("employee")
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="empId") 
private Employee employee;
```